# Overriding typeadhead default behaviour

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override the default behavior for bootstrap typeahead feature. 
As per the current behavior the highlighted element is selected when I press tab as in the following [link](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

To move to the next element , say another textbox next to it, i need to press tab again.
What I want is the current element to be selected and the next element highlighted on one tab press only.
I am using angularjs and bootstrap.

I tried the following code:

`$scope.focusNext = function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#nextTextBox').focus(); }, 20);
        };`

and on the first text box have added the following attribute :

`typeahead-on-select='focusNext()'`

This is working , however I dont want to set a timeout , but looking for a more elegant solution for the problem.
TIA

Comment: why do you need the timeout?

Comment: The focus is somehow not shifting without timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a directive like this one:

```js
var myModule = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myModule.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
});
myModule.directive('ignoreTab', function($timeout) {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('keydown', function (evt) {
      if (evt.which === 9) {
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
          element.nextAll('input').first().focus();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
  <h4>Static arrays</h4>
  <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
  <input ignore-tab="" typeahead-focus-first="true" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" />
  <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
  <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
  <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" />
</div>
```